# Remove CiviCRM logo from Invoice pdf?

Tags: pdf, invoice, logo

I am on Wordpress 4.9.5 and Civi 5.0.1.
Please see the screen shot of a downloaded pdf invoice. I would really like to remove that CiviCRM logo or replace it with my own.  Is there a configuration somewhere I can do that?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The invoice is generated based on the template "Contributions - Invoice". It contains a line to the logo ({$resourceBase}/i/civi99.png" height = "34px" width = "99px") that you would need to replace.

You can find teh message templates by Navigating to >>Administer >>CiviMail >>Message Templates in the tab "System Workflow Messages"

Comment: Thank you.  That solved it. I will be posting another issue that on the pdf invoices that I hope you can help with .

Answer (score 0):

I think a great way to make this easier would be to show the profile picture of the admin user at this place. Also I think the standard CiviCRM logo should adhere to the "Show 'powered by' setting" in civicrm/admin/setting/misc I will create a PR for the later option.